# How to show datetime field as a float?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a column which is of type datetime. The datepart is always 1899-12-30. I'm intressed in the time part.

Here are some examples:

```
Original field data:          Desired return value:
1899-12-30 07:45:00.000       7,75 or 7,45
1899-12-30 13:00:00.000       1 or 13 
1899-12-30 08:00:00.000       8
1899-12-30 13:30:00.000       13,5 or 13,30
1899-12-30 18:15:00.000       18,25  or 18,15
```

What is the best manner to get the desired outputs?

** I am using sql server 2005.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using a `datetime` field for just time data? Why not use a `time` field?

Comment: My application accepts just floats.

Comment: I wasn't asking about your application - I was asking about the database schema. If you've got the same date for each value, you only need a `time` field, not a `datetime` field.

Comment: Actually, I dont know that. This was done by someone else:)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  1.0 * datepart(hour, yourDateColumn) + 0.01 * datepart(minute, yourDateColumn)
from    yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `DATEDIFF` to find the number of milliseconds since midnight 1899 December 31st, and then divide by the number of milliseconds in an hour:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("ms", ColumnName, '1899-12-31 00:00:00') / 3600000.0 FROM Foo
```

Or if your data is only precise to the nearest second:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("s", ColumnName, '1899-12-31 00:00:00') / 3600.0 FROM Foo
```

Comment: I got this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fcb0/6)**

```
SELECT t.dt,
       CAST(DATEPART(hour, t.dt) AS NVARCHAR(2)) +
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(minute, t.dt) = 0 THEN ''
       ELSE ',' END + 
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(minute, t.dt) = 0 THEN ''
       ELSE CAST(DATEPART(minute, t.dt) AS NVARCHAR(2)) END AS rr
FROM Table1 t
```

Result:

```
|                              DT |    RR |
-------------------------------------------
| December, 30 1899 07:45:00+0000 |  7,45 |
| December, 30 1899 13:00:00+0000 |    13 |
| December, 30 1899 08:00:00+0000 |     8 |
| December, 30 1899 13:30:00+0000 | 13,30 |
| December, 30 1899 18:15:00+0000 | 18,15 |
```